# PHP Curl Как вытянуть значения?

Tags: php, парсер, curl, simple-html-dom

Всем привет! В общем нужно вытянуть значение из 
             (div class="yt-lockup yt-lockup-tile yt-lockup-video clearfix"
             data-context-item-id="Aj0F3D_XDm0" data-visibility-
             tracking="CEEQ3DAYAyITCMTl0sOg-tICFUfMHQodzD4EnCj0JEDtnNz-w7vBngI=")

Нужно вытянуть значение data-context-item-id.
Помогите добрые люди) Вот что пробовал....

```
 $ch = curl_init();

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);//инициализация cURL

 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);//максимальное время для работы функций cURL
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");//все кодировки

 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);//включение заголовков в вывод
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);//не проверять SSL сертификат
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);//не проверять HOST SSL
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'youtube.txt');//сохранить куки в файл

 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);//следования любому заголовку
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS,30);//максимальное количество принимаемых редиректов

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true );

 $a = curl_exec($ch);
  //отслеживание ошибок
  if($a === FALSE){
  echo "cURL Error: " .curl_error($ch);
   }

   $html = new simple_html_dom();
   $html->load($a,true,false);
   $links = array();
   $imgs = array();
   foreach($html->find("div.yt-lockup yt-lockup-tile yt-lockup-video clearfix ")as $s){
   $links[] = $s->data-context-item-id;
}
```

Comment: там разве не js скрипт? который нужно сначала выполнить, а потом появится значение data-context-item-id?

Comment: @hitcode ну я могу вытянуть первые 5 значений, а потом нет)

Answer (score -1):

Во первых лучше использовать какую нибудь готовую либу типа [guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/) чтобы не мучаться с curl (хотя она тоже использует его внутри)

Во вторых проще (ну мне по крайней мере) регуляркой типа

```
preg_match('/div class="yt-lockup yt-lockup-tile yt-lockup-video clearfix"\s+data-context-item-id="(?<value>[^"]+)/s', $content, $matches);
$value = $matches['value'];
```